# Join Table With Multiple Condition Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have the sql below:

```
$result = DB::table('tblA')
        ->join('tblB','tblB.id', '=', 'tblA.photoid')
        ->join('tblB','tblB.id', '=', 'tblA.linkedphotoid')
...
```

I have tblA with photoid and linkedphotoid and both link to one same table(tblB) and same column.

How to write it in laravel sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add OR condition in your join

```
$result = DB::table('tblA')
          ->join('tblB', function($join) {
            $join->on('tblB.id', '=', 'tblA.photoid')->orOn('tblB.id', '=', 'tblA.linkedphotoid');
          })
          ->get();
```